# Android Studio: Signing issue after upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio, signing

I recently upgraded my android studio from 0.2.6 to 0.2.11. The Build - > "generate signed apk" wizard which was opening up in 0.2.6 is not coming up here. Instead it shows a dialog like :

For Gradle-based projects, the signing configuration should be specified in the Gradle build scripts.
See the Gradle User Guide for more info.

I even added the below lines in build.gradle file:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }

        myConfig {
            storeFile file("other.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        foo {
            debuggable true
            jniDebugBuild true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
        }
    }
```

Could anyone please tell me what could be the issue?

Or also could you please let me know how to downgrade my studio?

Thanks

Comment: Yesterday I was having this problem and today it's gone.

Comment: When I start coding and testing the problem returns.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary fix for your issue is to restart Android Studio. After a cold start, Android Studio will let you access the "generate signed apk" wizard once before again warning you that you have to change your build.gradle.

As Shai mentioned, this will be fixed in a future release. Please see the links in his post.

Comment: It must be run immediately after Android Studio starts up, before any background compilation / building begins, which usually happens automatically once Android Studio finishes starting up.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is got fixed in Android Studio v 0.2.13 as expected.

[Bug fixed by Android Studio Developer Team](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60762)

[Google Android Thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60762)

Answer (score 1):

I copied `gradlew` from the android studio to my project root directory

Then I added this to my build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("mykeystore")
            storePassword "mypassword"
            keyAlias "my alias"
            keyPassword "mypassword"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Then I did

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

from my project root directory

This way I got the signed apk in `build/apk`

Too bad I wasn't able to do the same via IDE

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using "gradle installRelease" and coping the release APK from build/apk folder.

I am not sure why we are getting this, I do have my signingConfigs setup properly in build.gradle.