# How to signed my android project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, apk

My first Android project is finished. But I am not generate this project in android studio.
I do Build -> Generate Signed APK but i get this error.

> For Gradle-based projects, the signing configuration should be
>   specified in the Gradle build scripts.See the Gradle User Guide for
>   more info."

This is sample image

http://www.tjod.org/questions/keystore.png

This is my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("/Applications/AndroidNew/turkjinekolojidernegi.jks")
            storePassword "******"
            keyAlias "******"
            keyPassword "******"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.1.1.jar')
}
```

I cleaned build file. Build -> Rebuild Project. but not fixed.

Comment: Check [Generate Signed APK failed][1]
for an answer. It worked for me

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185560/android-studio-signing-issue-after-upgrade

Comment: İ tried this but not worked for me. How to change my build.gradle file ? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Android Studio 0.3.7 and it now works fine :D

First make sure you have into you `<application>` entry of the `AndroidManifest.xml` the following entry `android:debuggable="false"`

Then go to the **Build** menu option, and choose "**Generate Signed APK**". Create a key store or use an existing one, click "Next", change destination if desired. and decide if you want to use ProGuard or not, then click "Finish". And you have now you APK ready for production :).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio version 0.2.11?

If so, then you might be running into this bug:
[Android Studio: Signing issue after upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185560/android-studio-signing-issue-after-upgrade)

Comment: Today published android 2.0.13 and problem fixed. Thamk you